# SQL fetch results by concatenating words in column

Tags: sql, string-search

I have column `store_name` (`varchar`). In that column I have entries like `prime sport`, `best buy`... with a space. But when user typed concatenated string like `primesport` without space I need to show result `prime sport`. how can I achieve this? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE replace(store_name, ' ', '') LIKE '%'+@SEARCH+'%' OR  STORE_NAME LIKE '%'+@SEARCH +'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `replace()`

You can replace the white space in the query then use `like`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE replace(store_name, ' ', '') LIKE '%primesport%'`

It will work for entries like 'prime soft' querying with 'primesoft'

Or you can use regex.

Comment: There is a problem with '.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz will you elaborate? the question asks for only space (" ")

Comment: LIKE '%primesport%' is true.

Comment: After like you should pass string.

Comment: thnks fixed the quote

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have much idea, and even I am searching for it. But may be what I know works for you, You can achieve this by performing different type of string operations:

```
Mike can be Myke or Myce or Mikke or so on.
Cat an be Kat or katt or catt or so on.
```

For this you should write a function to generate number of possible strings and then form a SQL Query using all these, and query the database.

A similar kind of search in known as [`Soundex Search from Oracle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm) and [`Soundex Search from Microsoft`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx). Have a look of it. this may work.

And overall make use of functions like [`upper`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) and [`lower`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower).